# Hint to integrate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x\text{ ?}$$ The answer is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$, but I don't seem to get a way to reach there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the Maclaurin series for the function

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^{n-1}x^n\over n}$$

Then you're integrating

$$\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-x)^{n-1}\over n}\,dx.$$

Now switch the integral with the sum and...

Comment: That series is also called the Mercator series